# How to add calculated column in a main table that would calculate sum from another table in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two table that are **not related**:

**Table1:**

[image]

**Table2:**

[image]

How can I simply add a calculated column that would  grab a sum(TotalIncurred) per each `PolicyNumber` where `DateCreated >=` `10/19/2018`

**So desirable result should be:**

[image]

Do I need to relate those two tables first?

Or there is a way to calculate it based on PolicyNumber without creating a relationship?

I tried to create a seperate table first, that would group all TotalIncurred and PolicyNumber:

```
LossesTableTest = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(fact_Losses, fact_Losses[PolicyNumber] <> BLANK()),
              fact_Losses[PolicyNumber]
              ),
            "TotIncurred", CALCULATE(SUMX(fact_Losses, fact_Losses[TotalIncurred]))
)
```

And then add calculated column `LossPerPolicy` in a main table:

```
LossPerPolicy = 

    SUMX(
        FILTER(LossesTableTest, LossesTableTest[PolicyNumber] = fact_Premium[PolicyNumber] ), 
        LossesTableTest[TotIncurred]
        )
```

But the numbers are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
TotalIncurred =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table2'[TotalIncurred] ),
    TREATAS ( VALUES ( 'Table1'[PolicyNumber] ), 'Table2'[PolicyNumber] ),
    FILTER ( 'Table2', 'Table2'[DateCreated] >= '10/19/2018' )
)
```

untested but seems like it will work :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it does not give me the right numbers

Answer (score 0):

I prefer relating tables for this solution. If you have an unique policy number in table1, you should relate them to make this easier. If it's not unique, you can add a third table with unique policy numbers and relate them. The add a calculated column like this:

```
SUMX (    
    FILTER(
        RELATEDTABLE(Table2),
        'Table2'[DateCreated] >= '10/19/2018' 
    ), 
    'Table2'[TotalIncurred]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try using SUMX here, Although I have no way to test it :)

```
TotalIncurred =
SUMX (
    'Table1',
    CALCULATE (
        VALUES ( 'Table2'[TotalIncurred] ),
        FILTER (
            'Table2',
            'Table2'[DateCreated] >= '10/19/2018'
                && 'Table1'[PolicyNumber] = 'Table2'[PolicyNumber]
        )
    )
)
```